# Renumber listing

Tags: numbering, listings

I am using `listings` to add some codes, as shown in the image
[image]

For this I use the following:

```
\lstset{language= python, breaklines=true,basicstyle=\footnotesize}

\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt}
```

And

```
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
sage: s0.series(z,6)
1 + 1*z + 2*z^2 + 5*z^3 + 14*z^4 + 42*z^5 + Order(z^6)
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
sage: s1.series(z,6)
1*z^(-1) + (-1) + (-1)*z + (-2)*z^2 + (-5)*z^3 + (-14)*z^4 + (-42)*z^5 + Order(z^6)
\end{lstlisting}
```

what I am looking for is that the number on the left in the second box starts the count from 3 (because it is the third line), and as you can see it starts from 1, as in the first box.  Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either an explicit value for the `firstnumber` argument, or select `last` if you want the numbering to continue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xfp,refcount}

\lstset{
  language=python,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
sage: s0.series(z,6)
1 + 1*z + 2*z^2 + 5*z^3 + 14*z^4 + 42*z^5 + Order(z^6)
\end{lstlisting}

% firstnumber set to an explicit fixed value
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,firstnumber=3]
sage: s1.series(z,6)
1*z^(-1) + (-1) + (-1)*z + (-2)*z^2 + (-5)*z^3 + (-14)*z^4 + (-42)*z^5 + Order(z^6)
\end{lstlisting}

% firstnumber set to continue from the last value
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,firstnumber=last]
sage: s3.series(z,6)
1 + 1*z + 2*z^2 + 5*z^3 + 14*z^4 + 42*z^5 + Order(z^6)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: firstnumber worked perfect, thanks